# Project won't build after Android Studio and Gradle update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I just updated Android studio from 1.8.11 to 1.9.2. First time I opened my project after the update, it said something like "import new gradle and syn project". I pressed it cause my project wouldn't build at all, so i though hey maybe this would work. Android studio then downloaded and installed Gradle 2.1, but now when i try to build i get a `cannot resolve symbol R` on all `com.projectName.R`, in all of my class files.

Anyone experiencing same problem or know how to fix it? Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: This is the error i get when opening an old 1.8.11 project into 1.9.2. `Error:The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.12.2). The recommended version is 0.14.1.
<a href="fixGradleElements">Fix plug-in version and re-import project</a>`

When i click the link thats when it updates Gradle from 1.12 to 2.1 and this is when my com.projectName.R imports stop working.

Comment: your project is not compiling, so not generating R classes neither. Do you have any other errors ?

Comment: No, this is the only error. it comes right after my Messages Gradle Build writes ":androids:processReleaseManifest FAILED", then it writes "Error:Execution failed for task ':androidrss:processReleaseManifest'.
> NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist." All other step before this it writes "UP-TO-DATE" etc ":androidrss:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE"

Comment: how are you builing your project. (and just fyi, it's Gradle, without a N ;))

Comment: Tried multiple things, did a clean, make, rebuild, Syn Project with Gradle Files. Non of these steps worked.

Comment: Updated post with a exact error description when opening a old 1.8.11 project into 1.9.2

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and the problem was that `AndroidManifest.xml` file in one of my modules had no `<application>` tag in it.

Adding an empty `<application />` tag solved the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.package.mine">
    <application />
</manifest>
```

If you don't have any files with missing  tag, or you don't experience the same problem, I suggest you try to execute in command line:

```
gradlew assembleDebug --info
```

and see what is at the end of the output, just before the error. The extra information from `--info` parameter is what helped me to decrypt my problem.